# css - border-width, border background and background issue in safari 5.x issue

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add a background image to the border of an element in an html document:

You can see it here : 
HTML:

```
<a href="#">Something</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    border-width:10px;
    border-color:#006;
    background-color: #CF0;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://heroeswallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/cute-twitter-background.jpg) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://heroeswallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/cute-twitter-background.jpg) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
    border-image: url(http://heroeswallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/cute-twitter-background.jpg) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
}
```

And : http://jsfiddle.net/gqv8z/

This doesnt work in Safari 5.x, but it works in safari 6, and FF and Chrome... 
(why the background of the image becomes the background of the element?)

So i have 2 questions.

1. Is any solution for this, if so what solution, if not...
2. If Safari 5.x doesn't support a background for the border, how can i target this specific browser with CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: it works in safari 5.x here. it just needs loading time. so you could load it earlier in your css and overrule it direct after.

Comment: i am using 5.1.7, and it doesnt work, i see the background image in the border YES, but the background image it is not suppose to be the background of the element

Comment: If you are tring to target a specific browser, I'd use Modernizr to target the feature. http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: arrrgh. i would not use a bunch of js code just for a border.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a -o- border image like so.

```
-o-border-image: url(http://heroeswallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/cute-twitter-background.jpg) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
```

Try adding this and tell me if it works or not.

Comment: sorry, What do you mean by -o- border image?